# Get json data response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

From this

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'post',
    dateType: 'json',
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>buyer/get_address',
    data: { data: $id },
    success: function (resp) {
        alert(resp); //retuns whole result
        alert(resp.address_id); //returns undefind
    }
})
```

I get this in browser console:

```
{
  "address_id": "10",
  "user_id": "81",
  "address_as": "wholesale",
  "receiver_name": "Karamjeet Singh",
  "address": "street no 1,",
  "zip_code": "11111111",
  "phone": "222222222222",
  "province": "14",
  "regency": "Bali",
  "sub_district": "",
  "status": "1",
  "created": "28 Oct 2013 , 11 : 06 : 06 am",
  "updated": "28 Oct 2013 , 11 : 06 : 06 am"
}
```

Can anybody tell me how can I access all data according to response that is in individual variables?

Comment: What are you getting for `alert(resp.d.address_id)` ?

Comment: There's a typo in your ajax configuration. `dateType:'json',` should be `dataType: 'json'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it not `dateType:'json',` it should be `dataType:'json'`

```
  ....
  type : 'post',
  dateType:'json',
 //^^^^^^---here 
  ...
```

hence your JSON returned in treated as string and not object. you can however use `JSON.parse()`  but fixing the `dateType` to `dataType` should work

Comment: Thanks sir .actually i am using IDE .in this when i put dateType:'json' it converted all vars in green color so i not actully see it carefully.thanks again sir for rectify my fault so rapidly.its working fine after changing .

Comment: Sir your Profile pic is so dangrous.what intimation it depicts? :)

Answer (score 1):

Correct the mistake shown  by  @bipen and in success function :

```
success: function(resp)
{
       alert(resp[0].address_id);
}
```

Working Fiddle :[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/D8yUS/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

In View:

```
$('#mybtn').click(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                dateType: 'json',
                url: '../Home/test',
                data: {  },
                dataType: 'json',                
                success: function (resp) {

                    alert(resp.val); //returns undefind
                }
            })
        });
```

Controller:

```
public class t
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
        public string val { get; set; }
    }
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public JsonResult test()
        {
            var dataitem = new t { MyProperty =1,val="jeet" };
            return Json(dataitem, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```